# how can 3d shape data project onto your 2d screen in computer graphics?

Tags: graphics, model, 3d, rendering, mesh

So correct me if i'm wrong, but I think all elements in 3d graphics are meshes.

So the question is really, how do you take mesh data and create a 2d projection based on the mesh data, the camera location, rotations of camera & mesh, etc.

I realize this is fairly complicated and I would be satisfied by just knowing what the technical term for this is called so I may search and research it.

Comment: Fairly complicated? Good one. That's basically all graphics engines do!

Comment: Not all elements in 3D graphics are meshes. Granted, the way graphics cards work makes it beneficial if they are meshes. However it perfectly possible to do stuff without a single mesh. This can be beneficial in software renderers where the data often can be a mathematical primitive other than a mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about [3D projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) on Wikipedia.